# JWT Token and CSRF

Tags: javascript, php, http, jwt

I am still not clear in regards to the JWT and CSRF working together. I understand the fundamentals for the JWT (what it is and how it works). And I also understand the CSRF when used with sessions. Similarly I understand that there are risks involved with storing the JWT in localStorage and that's why you need the csrf token. So my question is, how do I use them both. For simplicity say that I have a login page.

1) I have the user signing in and once the email and password are consumed if the user is authenticated the server will send a CSRF and will store a httpOnly cookie with the JWT (how do I set the cookie using PHP). What I understood is that you can use `header('Set-Cookie: X-Auth-Token=token_value; Secure; HttpOnly;');`please confirm if thats the way to do it.

2) Once I have set the cookie with the JWT. How I am sending the CSRF token with subsequent requests> From what I understood, you set them in the headers. So if I am making an Ajax request I will put them in the headers.

3) Once the request is made and the CSRF token is sent along with the request. How is the validation made. What am I comparing?

Last, is this safe to implement!

I would highly appreciate if you could include as much details as possible.

Comment: The SameSite Cookie Attribute can be used to address this problem, and has had wide browser support for a couple of years. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite#browser_compatibility

Answer (score 27):

One approach that I've seen and used myself is to include the CSRF token inside the JWT as a claim. So when the user sends username and password, you can do the following:

1. If username and password are correct, proceed with the following listing.
2. Create a new JWT and include a generated CSRF token in the payload as a claim, then sign the JWT.
3. Respond to client's authentication request by setting an `HTTPOnly` cookie which contains the JWT. This ensures that only the browser (not the client side app and possibly malicious scripts) has access to the JWT. It's also a good idea to set the cookie to [`secure`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.2.5). This prevents the browser from sending the cookie if an unsecured communication channel is used (i.e. not https).
4. When setting the JWT cookie, you should also set an HTTP header which will also contain your generated CSRF token. Note that now you will have the CSRF token in two places—inside the JWT cookie and in an HTTP header.
5. In your client app, store the CSRF token from the header into localstorage.
6. For each request, take the CSRF token from localstorage and include it as a request header (the cookie containing the JWT is passed along automatically by the browser).
7. The server should read the JWT from the cookie, validate its signature and read the CSRF token from the JWT's payload. Then it should compare it against the CSRF token that's in the request header. If they match, the server can continue processing the request.

I suggest you to watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67mezK3NzpU) talk about JWTs. It goes into more details about the same approach (also with nice diagrams). Feel free to watch the entire talk or if you're interested specifically in CSRF, start from [36:29](https://youtu.be/67mezK3NzpU?t=36m29s).

The following is a slide (from the presentation linked above) that demonstrates how JWT and CSRF tokens could be used together. I annotated it with red numbers which correspond to the listing above.
[image: Sequence diagram of JWT and CSRF working together]

Comment: Could you clarify for #4. When you say in the same response you mean echo to client or set it in the header?

Comment: @Gacci set it in the header

Comment: I am so sorry. I am still confused. Is the header in #4 part of the header #3. Are both the same? What I understand is that you set two cookies one with the JWT (secure and HttpOnly) and another cookie (secure only). Then the secure-only cookie is stored in the localStorage and then compared to the one with in the jwt. Is that correct?

Comment: Edited my answer. In #3 you set an HTTPOnly secure cookie which contains your JWT. The JWT itself should also contain your CSRF token. In #4 you set an HTTP header (not a cookie) which also contains your CSRF token. In your webapp you can only read the HTTP header containing the CSRF token. So when you receive a response from the server to your auth request, read the HTTP header containing the CSRF token and store it in browser's localstorage. Later, when you make another request to the server, read the CSRF token from localstorage and set it as a request header.

Comment: Is the JWT.CSRF randomly generated on each login request or does it work like a global secret key that is shared by every user?

Comment: Saving csrf token in the browser localstorage is dangerous.

Answer (score -1):

The common paradigm to defend against CSRF it to generate a token for each "form", and validate that the token that was set for the specific form is correct.

That way, attacker can't guess the token therefore can't make an external form that sends to your server.

Usually, the method to set that token is via `Cookie` and the client app will attach it to some custom header, that will give you an additional protection, then, the server should compare between the cookie value and the header value.

It is **important** that the token will be valid only for one session, otherwise, an attacker can reuse the same token that he got in the attack vector.

JWT, is a method to authenticate the user to the system not to validate that the request was valid.

I will try to explain by example, assume you are didn't implemented any protection against CSRF, but you do have a mechanism to authenticate your users (with usage of JWT), so the user logged in with the correct user & pass, your server will send a JWT, the client will save it to localStorage / memory.
Now, the attacker can craft a form on his site that will point to your server, assume that he knows the users JWT token (he got it with other methods like MITM), all he needs to do is to trick the user into going his page with the form, and the form will be sent to you with any problem, your server will accept the request and the attack will succeed.

If you implement any CSRF mechanism, the attacker at the example will not be able to guess the current token, therefore your server will ignore his request.

Comment: I understand the difference between authentication and authorization. My question is how to do it, in other words what exactly I am comparing. I understand the concepts perfectly fine!

Comment: In order to add CSRF, as I've wrote, you should pass a token via Cookie, and the client app will attach it to the form as hidden field or to the ajax request via headers. Then you can compare on the server side that the token in the cookie has the same value in the additional field (or the header).

Comment: this is backwards.you aren't vulnerable to csrf id you store token in localstorage. you are if yout store the token in cookies and use that as auth, because it's added automatically to the req.you chould add csrf protection as a header, because an attacker can't add custom headers automatically

Comment: You are correct, basically, whenever you use only cookie to auth a user, you are vulnerable  to CSRF. Usage of JWT can prevent CSRF attacks if sent as headers

Comment: maybe you should focus on safely storing your jwt token using web workers